# How to remote desktop a computer over internet

Tags: windows, internet, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote connection to a PC over internet](https://superuser.com/questions/55718/remote-connection-to-a-pc-over-internet)
>   [Free remote desktop app good for working with someone computer illiterate?](https://superuser.com/questions/103644/free-remote-desktop-app-good-for-working-with-someone-computer-illiterate)

My sister is beginning to use computer/windows XP and has got internet connection. This is her home PC.Now she has many issues involving using it, installing anti-virus and other software, some or the other issues. and it's difficult for me to tell her over phone how to fix it, understand the error messages etc etc. Since she has decently fast internet connection, I am wondering how many ways are there to achieve that I can do remote desktop on her machine from my machine and fix up her system, when she has any issues.

My system also runs windows XP.

Any 3rd party remote desktop client/server software I can install on my machine and guide her to install on her machine and from then on take control of her system, whenever I want.

Ideally, I am looking for something simple lightweight, basic user interface,which doesn't depend on how she connects to internet and how I connect to internet, windows version, even OS so are there solutions where I can provide support from my Mac as well..whereas she doesn't have to change a thing on her machine..

Comment: And: [What's the best Remote Desktop Application?](http://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application/1812#1812), [Best Performing Remote Desktop solution (for LAN)](http://superuser.com/questions/101453/best-performing-remote-desktop-solution-for-lan/101464#101464), [Remote connection to a PC over internet](http://superuser.com/questions/55718/remote-connection-to-a-pc-over-internet/55722#55722)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx).  Cross platform. Easy to use. There is even a portable, no need to install, version.

Comment: yeah, just finished experimenting with this. This is perfect solution.

Comment: I force my family to use this as well. Otherwise I'd had committed suicide by now.

Comment: It saves lives..

Comment: @BojanK: Truer words were never spoken.

Answer (score 4):

The VNC protocol allows you to see and control others desktops. Since it's a protocol there are different clients and servers. 
On of them is tighvnc http://www.tightvnc.com/ which is free and open source software.
And multiplatform as well.

Comment: There's also UltraVNC ( http://www.ultravnc.org/ ) which I've found is really good at supporting current versions of Windows (TightVNC, unfortunately, lagged behind on Vista and Windows 7 for a very long time, and I eventually had to switch all my clients over to UltraVNC because file transfers, in particular, are not compatible between these two clients).  +1 becuase TightVNC is a great product, and it's very fast (despite the history of compatibility with the newest versions of Windows being the big show-stopper for me).  =(

Answer (score 1):

You do know about the built-in remote-desktop in windows? There's also a client for Mac. 
It's not feature rich - but good for some quick maintainance.