# Control computer over internet

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remote desktop a computer over internet](https://superuser.com/questions/342129/how-to-remote-desktop-a-computer-over-internet)

Hello i have moved from my home country Denmark to America. This have left a gab in my family as i am apparently the only one who are able to handle a computer. When i lived in Denmark was this not a major problem as i could always come by, but right now am i on the other end of the world, so this is not an option!
Now i know there are a lot a programs there allow me to control the computer, Remote Dekstop that is integrated in windows for an example. But my father is behind a firewall, and my mother is part of a larger network where they do not have port forwarding.

Are there any program out there there can let my take control of their computer, for an example where i am the server, or where we use an external server?

Comment: Something like [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/index.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) behind firewalls, and it works just fine. Also [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com) works same way. Both are free for non commercial usage.

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial application, but which is free for use for non-commercial usage, called Teamviewer, which will probably solve your problem.

Else you will have to configure something more complicated. For example, if you have somewhere a server with a public IP address you can:

- make them connect to your server with ssh with the -R option so that you can connect via Terminal Services or vnc on their desktops
- configure a vpn server ( openvpn, pptp .. ) and setup a "family vpn" from where you would have access to there computers.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look on [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/#RemoteControl).

> LogMeIn Free offers free remote access to your desktop so you can open
>   files, check your email, run programs and stay productive from your
>   mobile device or any computer over the Internet

You simply create an account on their website and then you can control multiple computers just by installing a small client application which will allow you to view the desktop from web browser.

You can also send files with it, WakeOnLan and many other, useful things like e.g. monitoring computer's resources.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of controlling your computer is with your iPhone/iPod touch. There is a wonderful app called [iTeleport](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/) which effectively allows you to control your computer through your iPhone/iPod touch. You simply [get the app here](http://itunes.apple.com/app/iteleport-vnc/id286470485) for your mobile device, then you install either from [this file on Windows](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/download/iTeleportConnectService.v5.3.0.msi) or [this file on Mac](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/download/iTeleport%20Installer.v5.4.0.dmg). Finally, you follow these simple set-up instructions [for Windows](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/support/connect/windows) or [for Mac OS](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/support/connect/mac) (explanatory images are included in these explanations) and then you're done. Not only will you get the ability to control that computer over the Internet, but also you can take that control anywhere as an iPhone/iPod touch fits your pocket and you can carry it around very easily. I see this as a valid alternative to the other software that's been suggested mainly because of the mobility of the device used to take advantage of it. I have used it for my Linux computer via an iPod touch 4G and it works very well, despite the extra mile you have to run to get it working on Linux.

Finally, here's a snapshot of the app running on an iPhone:

[image: iTeleport on iPhone controlling a Windows XP desktop]

Edit: I am editing my answer to add [**this YouTube link**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMjXtT-k9jg) which shows iTeleport working on an iPad.