# Is there any software that I can control our team member's screen (or web browser/PowerPoint)?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, microsoft-powerpoint, remote-access

I'm a PM. I sometimes need to teach my team member something. So, I want a software that I can control the screen or a powerpoint presentation

Comment: Does PM mean prime minister? I use TightVNC.

Comment: What OS (and version if its windows). Is it within a lan or wan? Have you taken a look at the questions such as [this,](http://superuser.com/questions/101453/best-performing-remote-desktop-solution-for-lan) [this,](http://superuser.com/q/1585/4377) [this](http://superuser.com/q/117419/4377) or [this](http://superuser.com/q/55718/4377) and others under the remote desktop and remote access tags?

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer. Simple. Easy to use. There is even a portable version. Control their screen. Troubleshoot. Voice chat. Record. etc etc.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx